# Where does homebrew log?

Tags: homebrew

Does homebrew keep logs, and if so where?

I did a brew update which broke python support in macvim, and now I can't even get macvim to build. I'm hoping that there are some clues in the log.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew/

Homebrew creates log files in your Library folder at: `~/Library/Logs/Homebrew/`

You can view the log files by holding down <kbd>Option</kbd> and using the Finder menu item: **Go > Library**, then navigating to **Logs > Homebrew**.

Alternatively, you can use the **Console.app** application to browse to the log files.

#### Homebrew History

The default creation of individual log files was added during 2013 to Homebrew.

[Homebrew issue #10430](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10430) talks about logging and build errors. The issue report mentions no log file is kept but explains that a log can be created with the command format:

```
brew install <formula> 2>&1 | tee install.log
```

Answer (score 11):

Logs seem to be in ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew/...
They can be viewed either using command line utilities or the Console app.

Answer (score 3):

This works for the normal brew installs, but nothing is logged to these directories for services (for example, if you install `bind`, nothing is logged to `~/Library/Logs/Homebrew/bind`), possibly because you have to start services via sudo.

Comment: Would you expect logs for installed packages to be in a sub dir of ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew though?  I just looked, and was surprised that 2 packages I've installed do log to there.  My first guess would be that packages would log to the "standard" `/var/log` (or since homebrew works using `/usr/local`, maybe `/usr/local/var/log`)

Answer (score 3):

For `brew services` the logging location is specified in the service's corresponding plist file, using the following tags .e.g.

```
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/usr/local/var/log/that_service.log</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/usr/local/var/log/that_service.log</string>
```

The location of plist files for active services may be obtained by running:

```
brew services list
```