# How to figure out what is causing the ownership of /usr/local to change from my-username to root

Tags: macos, permission, homebrew

I use `homebrew` as a package manager for certain web development app. To keep `brew` up-to-date I run `update brew` every couple of days and also run `brew doctor`. Usually, this is fine and `brew` tells me I'm ready to brew.

Every now and then, however, I get the following error:

> Warning: /usr/local/etc isn't writable.
>
> This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
>   by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
>   install will fail during the link step.
>
> You should probably `chown` /usr/local/etc
>
> Warning: The /usr/local directory is not writable.
>   Even if this directory was writable when you installed Homebrew, other
>   software may change permissions on this directory. Some versions of the
>   "InstantOn" component of Airfoil are known to do this.
>
> You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
>   back to your user account.

It's easy enough to reset the permissions back to my username. Afterwards `brew` seems to be fine.

But what is causing this to happen?

Is there a log that shows what is causing the permissions to change?

Comment: No log but note that having /usr/local owned by rood is the Unix standard and so any build into there will expect it. Solution is don't mix a directory with both package manager (Homebrew) and standard Unix compilation - Use another directory for one of them

Comment: Adding software to the same location as a package manger uses is a bad idea, and so is changing the ownership and permissions on `/usr/local`. But if you insist then you could `make install` without using `sudo` for packages that you install yourself.

Comment: @Mark I also have this issue. It happens to me randomly, even when I haven't installed anything since I last had the issue.

Comment: @Others we need more info and another question re that problem

Comment: @Mark Isn't that this question? Where does it say that the issue involved software other than the software that is installed/upgraded by homebrew?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/are-my-permissions-for-usr-local-correct

Comment: Upgrading OS X usually resets /usr/local ownership and permissions.

Comment: @Others ah I read the quote from Homebrew rather than the question

Comment: What else did you install (manually or through any other package manager) on your Mac which was configured to default install in `/usr/local`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out Filewave is the culprit. Filewave is a system management software used by our school to push software updates. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 13):

I had this exact same issue, and it turns out Sophos auto-update was to blame. I figured this out by running: `sudo fs_usage | grep "usr/local"`

It took a while, but eventually I saw Sophos's helpfully named "Installation" daemon messing with /usr/local's permissions.

I'm still trying to figure out an appropriate work around for this behavior.

EDIT: I believe Sophos has fixed this issue, see the link in the comments of this answer. It seems to be fixed for me at least!

Comment: There's a discussion here: https://community.sophos.com/products/free-antivirus-tools-for-desktops/f/17/t/10029 This should be fixed in November 2015

Comment: @JoeZuntz Nice find! Awesome that they actually are pushing a fix.

Comment: @others thanks for this info. I was able to fix everything after upgrading to 10.11.1 and got homebrew working again, but more often than not, each time I went to do a brew upgrade, the permissions had changed again. It was bugging me what software kept changing the perms on /usr/local.

Comment: @TimX Yeah it kinda sucks... Luckily it looks like Sophos is patching it at the end of next week, November the 20th.

Answer (score 2):

I have just a rough idea how get the permission thief. This is not a solution to your problem, but more some sort of workaround.

What about writing a watchdog in Automator or with Hazel (folder actions) for watching this particular folder but instead of adding a function like Scale images you just use a shellscript which executes several shell commands:

- If the folder is changed in any way, just snapshot the permissions and the currently accessing process id with `fuser <foldername>`.
- then you lookup in the process table the process id (`ps auxwwwwww | grep <process id>`) and finally
- write an email to yourself with these collected informations.

Unfortunately I am no Automator sadhu, but I found out by Google there are plenty of solutions for such a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Time Machine, you can find the approximate time when permissions changed by exploring `Backups.backupdb` in Terminal. Use `ls -ld` in the timestamped folders, e.g.

```
ls -ld /Volumes/Backup/Backups.backupdb/Mac/2015-12-25-120000/Macintosh\ HD/usr/local
```

Which will show owner and group information.

Once you have the date the change occurred, you can sleuth out what else might have changed then on your system. A simple technique is to use Finder's File › Find and add a `Last modified date` criterion. Other good tools are [`find`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) and [`mdfind`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdfind.1.html) in Terminal.

Answer (score -1):

This is a side effect of updating your system; OS X probably does some across-the-board permission "repair" during the update process as /usr/local is nested in a root-owned folder.

Comment: AFAICT, upgrading to El Capitan is what caused the problem for me

Answer (score -3):

Have you used `Disk Utility` select `Macintosh HD` then run `Verify Disk Permission` and then `Repair Disk Permission` if needed, rather than doing it manually?

Now this shouldn't fix on your issue, but it's a good 'known' starting point to see when home-brew changes the permissions.  It could show up the underlying issue if you are luck.

Also `new update -v` for more verbose output, plus old logs are here `~/Library/Logs/Homebrew` as per [Where does homebrew log?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83827/where-does-homebrew-log)

Comment: `Disk Utility` wouldn't verify or repair permissions on `/usr/local` since this directory doesn't exist on a new install of Yosemite.

Comment: I checkd this hypothesis fully on Yosemite by creating a new `/usr/local` belonging to me, and running `DU`. There isn't any `/usr/local` within the `DU` log. And `/usr/local` still belongs to me.