# Cannot update 'macvim' formula using Homebrew?

Tags: install, homebrew, macvim, vi

I started my update from a clean output for `brew doctor` and then `brew update macvim` does not work:

```
brew upgrade macvim                                                                                               
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
macvim 7.4-99
==> Upgrading macvim
==> Downloading https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/archive/snapshot-99.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/macvim-7.4-99.tar.gz
==> ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-multibyte --with-macarchs=x86_64 --enable-perlinterp --enable-rubyinterp --enable-tc
Last 15 lines from /Users/meng/Library/Logs/Homebrew/macvim/01.configure:
--enable-rubyinterp
--enable-tclinterp
--with-tlib=ncurses
--with-compiledby=Homebrew
--with-local-dir=/usr/local
--enable-cscope
--enable-pythoninterp

configure: creating cache auto/config.cache
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/macvim20160315-26108-1x1n9dj/macvim-snapshot-99/src':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
macvim: disable ruby integration on 10.6 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/40255
macvim fails to build on Yosemite 10.10 with _SC_PHYS_PAGES error https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/47026
macvim failed to build on 10.6.8 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/38047
```

Any idea how to interpret the errors and how to fix it?

- Information about `clang`:

  ```
  bash-4.3$ which clang
  /usr/bin/clang
  bash-4.3$ clang
  clang: error: no input files
  bash-4.3$ clang --version
  Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
  Thread model: posix
  bash-4.3$
  ```
- Mac OS X version: 10.11.3
- I could not find brew log file `config.log`:

  ```
  ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew$ pwd
  /Users/qazwsx/Library/Logs/Homebrew
  ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew$ find . -type f -name config.log
  ./auctex/config.log
  ./diffutils/config.log
  ./emacs/config.log
  ./findutils/config.log
  ./gnu-indent/config.log
  ./gnu-sed/config.log
  ./gnu-tar/config.log
  ./gnu-which/config.log
  ./grep/config.log
  ./gzip/config.log
  ./less/config.log
  ./m4/config.log
  ./mkvtoolnix/config.log
  ./ncurses/config.log
  ./python/config.log
  ./quvi/config.log
  ./screen/config.log
  ./wdiff/config.log
  ```

Comment: (1) Does your C compiler work? If you type 'clang' in the terminal, what do you get? That seems to be the issue above, either that or some kind of permissions issue.
(2) What OS X version are you on?

Comment: (3) What's in the log file referenced in the error message?

Comment: I'm not sure where/how to find that log file?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/83827/145449